# Current_user doesn't return a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null

My current_user function does'nt work in my Post controller.
When i try to show /posts/1, that is 1st record maded in dbconsole i recive this error:

```
Couldn't find Post with id=1 [WHERE "posts"."user_id" = ?]
```

See my sources: post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

post model:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password
  .....
```

application controller:

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user
      private
      def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
      end
  end
```

the problem appear only in post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
...
    def show
    @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    end
...
end
```

Can onyone help me?

Comment: What is setting `session[:user_id]`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you at all. :user_id mean users ID. 
If i'll substitute current_user with session[:user_id] then i'll recive folowing error: undefined method `posts' for 8:Fixnum .

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to ask is, how is `session[:user_id]` getting set?  Is there a login process somewhere that sets the `session[:user_id]` to the logged in user?

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def show
 @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
end
```

The above will find posts belonging to the current_user with a specified `posts.id`. In your case for `posts/1`, `current_user.posts.find(params[:id])` would fire `SQL query` as below

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = ? AND "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 1]]
```

Make sure that you have a post record with `id=1` which belongs to `user_id=1`.

You are receiving the error, because in your post table, post entry with id=1 does not belong to user_id=1.

Comment: Emmm. I feel so noobie, sorry me please.